# Binary expansion has a zero in each even position is Lebesgue measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> **Exercise**: Show that the subset of points $A$ of the interval $[0,1]$ whose binary expansion has a zero in each even position of its expansion ($\frac{2}{3}=0,101010...\in A$ for example) is Lebesgue measurable and zero Lebesgue measure.

I know the following definition of measurability:
If $\mu^*:\mathscr{P}(\Omega)\to\mathbb{R}^+$ is a outer measure. Then $E_i$ is measurable with respect to $\mu^{*}$ iff $\forall A\in\mathscr{P}(\Omega)\:\:\mu^*(A)=\mu(A\cap E)+\mu(A\setminus E)$.

However despite knowing this definition I do not know if it supposed to be used.

I have no idea on how to solve this exercise.

**Question:**

Can someone provide an hint about how to prove measurability and that the measure is zero?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a countable intersection of (at each stage) a finite family of dyadic intervals.

Comment: You can write the set as an intersection of borel sets.

Comment: @FoobazJohn                   Could you please give some more hints? It has been hard to understand what I am supposed to do.

Comment: @T.Bongers            Could you please give some more hints? It has been hard to understand what I am supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L_0=[0, 1[$ ($\{1\}$ has null measure) for every $k\in\mathbb N$ we have
$$
L_0=\bigcup_{i=0}^{2^k-1}\left[\frac{i}{2^k}, \frac{i+1}{2^k}\right[
$$
if $n\in\left[\frac{i}{2^k}, \frac{i+1}{2^k}\right]$ then $n$ has a $0$ at position $k$ in its binary expansion if and only if $i$ is **even**. Then let
$$
L_k=\bigcup_{i=0}^{2^{2k-1}-1}\left[\frac{2i}{2^{2k}}, \frac{2i+1}{2^{2k}}\right[\\
L=\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb N}L_k
$$
clearly $L$ is Lebesgue measurable

Prove that
$$
\lvert L_n\cap L_{n-1}\cap\dotsb\cap L_1\rvert =\frac 12\lvert L_{n-1}\cap\dotsb\cap L_1\rvert
$$
then you can easily continue the proof.

Comment: I fail to see how you came to $L_0=\bigcup_{i=0}^{2^k-1}\left[\frac{i}{2^k}, \frac{i+1}{2^k}\right[$ and the realized $i$ must be even. I need the intuition. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Simply I separated the interval $[0, 1[$ in $2^k$ smaller intervals whose length is $\frac 1{2^k}$.
Let $k=3$ and $i=5=\mathtt{101}$ in base $2$ then $5/2^3=\mathtt{0.101}$ even in base $2$ (it's shifted to right by $3$ positions), so if $i$ is even then the least significant digit is $\mathtt 0$ (otherwise is $\mathtt 1$) that it'll be shifted to $k$ positions right when $i$ is divided by $2^k$.